# Python script to copy files

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that will copy files from one user’s home directory into another user’s home directory. I want it to copy the permissions, as well. I read the Python API and I think that the copy2 method does just that. However, when I run the following code, I get errors.

```
import shutil

src = raw_input("Please enter a source: ")
dst = raw_input("Please enter a destination: ")
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copyfiles.py", line 5, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 99, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../../../Desktop/byteswap.c'
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: The file `../../../../Desktop/byteswap.c` does not exist.  Note that the path is relative to the current working directory, so check with `print os.getcwd()` if it is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your current directory using `os.getcwd()`.